# Firebase FCM campaign targeting more users than I have downloads

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, google-play-console

So I set up a firebase project so I can send and schedule notifications for an application that I created. It worked fine in testing, and so I uploaded the app to the play store for closed Alpha testing. As of now, I have 5 testers, and only 3 downloads (1 uninstall) as can be seen
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWVjS.png)

However, when sending out a test notification, I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxAVe.png)

Its rather strange, however when I check the statistics after I sent the message, I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNQhn.png) showing only 4 sends. Is there any reason for this? Also after opening the notification with my phone, it still says 0 opens in the notification statistics for some reason. Any ideas why this may be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you upload app to Google Play Console your app was probably tested by them and you get Pre-Launch-Report. I think that this notification is sent to Google bots too.

You have probably also more 'audience' from USA in Firebase Dashboard than you really have because of this test bots. Check it.